# access django urls from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

```
 url(r'^(?P<code>[-\w]+)/$',views.Listing.as_view(),name='stat_details'),
```

How can I access this django url from my javascript file where I am sending an ajax call to this url:

**/mycode/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = {% url stat_details code='abc' %}.replace('abc', 'mycode');
  alert(url);
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success:function(result){
        populateTable(result.data.m_data);
      },
      error:function(xhr){
        alert("Fail"+ xhr.status+ " "+ xhr.responseText);
      }
  });
});
```

This doesn't work.Can someone help me in correcting this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,to avoid any confusion,update your URL as :

```
url(r'^stat_details/(?P<code>[-\w]+)/$',views.Listing.as_view(),name='stat_details'),
```

And then render your url just as a string like this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var code = your_code;
      var url = "/stat_details/"+ code;
      alert(url);
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          success:function(result){
            populateTable(result.data.m_data);
          },
          error:function(xhr){
            alert("Fail"+ xhr.status+ " "+ xhr.responseText);
          }
      });
    });

</script>
```

You don't need to complicate the URL request process and please don't forget the first **/** in **var url = "/stat_details/"+ code;**
And if the method is post,then you should also mention it. Thanks.

Comment: yeah this worked. can you also tell how can I access a django variable rendered to a html page in javascript?

Comment: @lola A Django template variable can be rendered as "{{your_variable}}" in Javascript code and  Don't forget the " " double quotes.

Comment: but this doesn't work if the javascript is in another file.